# Listview in Listview -> which adapter should be used (Android)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a Listview. In that Listview I have multiple textviews and again a listview.

First I always used the simpleadapter to fill my Listviews with data. But now I have added embedded a listview.

Which Adaplter do I have to use?! Because I think that this is not possible with the simpleadapter.

Main Activity layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:divider="@color/dark_grey"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:padding="4dp" />
```

Listview (lvData) item layout

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_deposit_depiting" />

    <ListView
        android:id="lvDepositDepitingList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

I always used the simple adapter that way:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (Deposit deposit : getCurrentList()) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name", deposit.getName());
        map.put("amount", String.valueOf(deposit.getAmount()));
        list.add(map);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.list_item_layout_deposit, new String[] { "name",
                    "amount" }, new int[] { R.id.tvDepositName,
                    R.id.tvDepositCurrentMonth });
    lvData.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I think I will have to extend an adapter and write a custom one. If that is what I have to do, which adapter should I extend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a class extending BaseAdapter and customize the view as you would like, check this link for help and guidelines [Custom Adapter Guide](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-listview-example-with-custom-adapter/)